Unable to update to the latest version of Mullvad via apt repo
I am unable to update to the latest version of Mullvad VPN due to the following error:

File has unexpected size (901 != 902). Mirror sync in progress?
Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:902 [weak]
   - SHA256:8d62918761d1f40624e5c06e8b33ad39d2b8bd9609cce0be5404c0a9bc26f4c2
   - SHA1:55ef1e20cd9dd946755451aa6b95c35ad20a4a04 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:343fcb0af8ba70f6634482b8dbad268b [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 03 Oct 2024 08:46:48 +0000


Does anyone know how to get around this issue?

Did you wait a few minutes and then try again? Perhaps a mirror sync was in progress. Mirror syncs occur several times each day. Alternately, you can try a different mirror.

@user535733 I did that a few times before I posted, waiting 5-10 mins each time and I was continuing to get the same issue.  I even tried on another computer running an older version of Ubuntu and it was doing the same thing.
However I just tried again now (one hour after my initial post) and it seems to be working fine now, so your explanation does appear to be accurate.  I hadn't ran into the issue before and was unsure how to approach it, so thank you.  Patience is a virtue.

You've not said what mirror you're using, so we can't even look up details. I've experienced this type of issue on the mirror provided by my ISP, and the job that did the sync failed & it wasn't noticed; so the problem remained until the next scheduled resync fixed the issue. Some mirrors sync multiple times per day, some only once; so it maybe more than minutes.

Coincidentally, there is a similar UbuntuForums thread. Looking over the output there, looks like the reliability problem is at the Mullvad end, not yours.
